# Adding shapefile to existing MXD using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, mxd, save

I am trying to add a shapefile to an already created MXD project in ArcMap 10.3.1. I run the code but nothing happens. I leave it below:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Cursos\Prueba\Mxd_a_shape.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

hola = r"C:\Cursos\Prueba\hola.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(hola,"prueba")
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("prueba")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,layer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

del mxd
```

Is something wrong with the code just described?

Comment: You never saved your change before deleting the `mxd` object.

Comment: All right. I placed 'mxd.saveACopy (r "C: \ Courses \ Test \ Mxd_a_shape2.mxd") before 'del mxd' and it worked for me.

Is it possible to delete the previous project and leave only the copy?

Comment: Probably better to make a subdirectory, put the old MXD(s) there, then saveAsCopy into the original dir.